# Navigation Drawer not working since adding support for android-P

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

I am building an application that allows user to shop for products. I recently made changes to my gradle build files to support android-P and use the new material design components but since then the navigation drawer in my Home Page activity isn't working even though i have not modified any code related to it.

By not working I mean that the navigation drawer doesn't even open.
The button in the action bar does nothing and the siding gesture just makes the screen pitch black until i let go.

Project : [ShoppingApp : Github](https://github.com/codeluster/ShoppingApp)

Relevant code in HomePage.java

```
        //Adding Navigation Drawer
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.home_page_drawer);

    NavigationView

 navigationView = findViewById(R.id.home_page_nav_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.nav_drawer_sign_up:
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, SignUp.class));
                        break;

                    case R.id.homepage_drawer_your_cart:
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, YourCart.class));
                        break;

                    case R.id.homepage_drawer_account:
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, UserAccount.class));
                        break;
                }

                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

layout file of Home Page

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_page_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.tanmay.shoppingapp.HomePage">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/d68f8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/homePageToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:title="Home"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/productList_homepage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/djid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up Please" />


</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/home_page_nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/home_page_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/home_page_drawer" />
```

Comment: use `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` above `linerlayout` try this one

Comment: I cannot use a Coordinator Layout instead of a Drawer Layout because a Coordinator Layout doesn't come with methods to trigger opening and closing of the navigation drawer